# JOIN data from ARRAY or nested values

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2 to present some enumerated data to a postgresql query. This data needs to be joined to the tables I am using to return the data I want so I can get them in the correct order. It appears psycopg2 only allows the provision of data as an array or as a single bracket of values. Here is an example of one query attempt:

```
 SELECT table_a.foo, table_b.bar
 FROM table_a
 JOIN table_b USING(id)
 JOIN unnest(ARRAY[(0,34523), (1, 3453)]) AS baz (index, id) USING (id)
 ORDER BY baz.index ASC
```

As you can see I'm using the array to select the ids I want but also provide another column to order the rows, but I can't get the data to behave as a joined table. In this example I get the following error: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"

Instead of an ARRAY the data can be provided as: `((0,34523), (1, 3453))`

Unless psycopg2 allows for a VALUES list like: `VALUES (0,34523), (1, 3453)`?

I'm using postgresql 9.1.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find solution, which involves constructing the query string in parts:

```
    enumerated_ids = ','.join(self.cur.mogrify("(%s, %s)", x) for x in enumerate(ids))

    self.execute("""
        SELECT table_a.foo, table_b.bar
        FROM table_a
        JOIN table_b USING(id)
        JOIN (VALUES """+ enumerated_ids +""") AS baz (index, id) USING (id)
        ORDER BY baz.index ASC
    """, ())
```

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTANT: The accepted answer is very **dangerous** and should not be used.

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries states:

> If the variables containing the data to send to the database come from an untrusted source (such as a form published on a web site) an attacker could easily craft a malformed string, either gaining access to unauthorized data or performing destructive operations on the database. This form of attack is called SQL injection and is known to be one of the most widespread forms of attack to database servers. Before continuing, please print this page as a memo and hang it onto your desk.
>
> Psycopg can automatically convert Python objects to and from SQL literals: using this feature your code will be more robust and reliable. We must stress this point:
>
> Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

However, you can define your own adopter:

```
class Values(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.storage = value

def adapt_values(value):
    return AsIs("(VALUES(" + ", ".join(map(lambda x: str(x), value.storage)) + ")")

register_adapter(Values, adapt_values)

cur.execute("SELECT X, Y FROM Table JOIN %s V(A, B) ON A = X AND Y = B", [Values(my_values)])
```

Documentation: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#adapting-new-python-types-to-sql-syntax

Comment: The `enumerated_ids` variable is trusted though. And your example is just taking the string representation of the values which is insecure if the values come from an untrusted source. That's why I use `mogrify()`. Maybe I can create an adapter but that seems completely pointless.